# Why can't I use an OR operator in a switch case for strings in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

It says I cannot use an OR on two strings in a switch case (Dental || Vision). Would placing each option in its own separate case work or am I messing up the syntax? Much thanks

```
            switch (GR.planTypeFocus){
                case "Medical":
                    CreatePlanForMedical();
                    break;
                case "Dental" || "Vision":
                    //createPlanForDental_Vision
                    break;
                case "LTD" || "Life":
                    //createPlanForLTD_Life
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This syntax is not acepted, you can rather club multiple cases.

Answer (score 8):

Technically you achieve 'OR' by using fall through

```
switch (GR.planTypeFocus){
   case "Medical":
      CreatePlanForMedical();
      break;
   case "Dental":
   case "Vision":
       //createPlanForDental_Vision
       break;
    case "LTD":
    case "Life":
       //createPlanForLTD_Life
       break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use an "or", based on the context of your example:

```
        switch (GR.planTypeFocus){
            case "Medical":
                CreatePlanForMedical();
                break;
            case "Dental":
            case "Vision":  //<-- here's how you do it
                //createPlanForDental_Vision
                break;
            case "LTD":
            case "Life":  //<-- this is how you do it
                //createPlanForLTD_Life
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Wow thanks I never knew you could place two cases together like that and have them execute the same line(s) of code.